Should I carry a parachute on GA flights?
The Eurofox aircraft that I have a share in does not have a parachute option fitted and there is no appetite for this at my club.
Would it be safe / reasonable / useful to just wear a parachute when flying? I'm thinking it's use case would really only be mid-airs or structural failure.
Furthermore, how much safer would this make each flight, statistically?
Thanks

Could you operate the parachute? -- Just a though: if you have structural issue, probably you cannot exit properly the aircraft. Air force uses different method to "exit" (so parachutes seems to be effective), so probably it may depend on aircraft type: what do your club use?

Sure, go ahead, why not?  Pilots spend most of their time looking down at screens these days, so mid-air collisions are becoming ever more likely.  PS re "Furthermore, how much safer would this make each flight, statistically"  -  well, let's see.  If a given flight has a 2% chance of fatality (yes I know that's not a realistic number) and wearing a parachute drops it to 1%, has the flight become 50% safer or is the correct number 100* ((99/98)-1) = 1.02% safer?

@GiacomoCatenazzi a Eurofox

Can you actually wear a parachute when sitting in the plane seats, without being ridiculously uncomfortable? Most planes aren't designed for parachute wearers.

Voting to close this as opinion based. There is no way to conclusively answer this question, and the risks mentioned-- midair and structural failure-- are almost vanishingly small compared to all the other reasons pilots crash. (Unless flying a glider, or doing aerobatics, but based on the description of the Eurofox club plane it doesn't sound these edge cases apply.)

Statistically, you're far more likely to have a spin/stall accident turning final than a midair. But then again statistically you're much more likely to crash your car on the way to the airfield than the plane. Statistics are somewhat pointless here.

How often do you think airplanes spontaneously come apart or hit each other in mid-air? These are things that just functionally do not happen outside of like kitplanes or formation flying. Nobody wears a chute because if you're in a scenario where jumping is even an option, you're almost certainly in a situation where gliding to a relatively safe landing site is a better option.

Glider pilots wear parachutes because the nature of the sport introduces a significant mid air collision risk in contest conditions with many gliders sharing chunks of sky. And outside those conditions, you have to have one on to sit in the seat, so you wear it anyway. In power planes, only if you are doing aerobatics, because the risk of the thing just falling apart on you just flying around in 1-2G flight is too small. Do you wear a crash helmet when you go up and down stairs?
